# How are you supposed to invoke php -B (--process-begin)?

Tags: php

On the command line, `php` can read code from STDIN and execute it:

```
$ echo '<?php echo "Executing stdin\n";' | php                                              
Executing stdin
```

I want to pass in a variable that will be made available to the STDIN code. I noticed the [`-B` option](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) seems to be a way to do this:

> -B --process-begin | PHP code to execute before processing stdin. Added in PHP 5.

When I try it though, nothing is echoed:

```
$ echo '<?php echo "Executing stdin with passed variable: $foo\n";' |
    php -B '$foo = "some value";'
```

Indeed, passing `-B` at all seems to break the code, as this does nothing:

```
$ echo '<?php echo "Executing stdin\n";' | php -B ''
```

How is the `-B` option supposed to be used? Is there any chance I can get it to do what I want?

#### Editorializing — 2014/4/9 Update

I can only assume that the “before processing stdin” part of the PHP documentation is incorrect.  It should read — as I understand it — “PHP code to execute before running code passed with -R or -F”. See **tencent**'s answer for more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -B flag is begin code meant to run before running the main code defined by -R.

The command line help shows this:

```
 php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
```

As you can see the -R flag is not optional in this use case.

To pass arguments, just put them in the args param.

```
 php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
```

Comment: Do you know what the 'before processing stdin' part of the `-B` docs is referring to? Neither `-R` nor `-F` reads code from STDIN.

Comment: The -R 'should' receive the STDIN arguments as $argv only if register_argc_argv is enabled I believe. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php